# Did he really say "What's your weight?"? [intonation]

Tags: wh-questions, direct-speech, intonation

> Did he really say "What's your weight?"? What an impolite question!

What intonation should I use at the end of the first sentence?

The first sentence is not a wh-question while "What's your weight?" is a wh-question, so I don't know how I should pronounce the first sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin English certainly does not use the same rise for all questions. Say your own examples out loud. Questions with wh-question words are usually flat like statements.

Comment: This is a good question!

Comment: For some wh-questions, doesn't intonation even vary depending on what you mean? E.g. "Why's that?" - you either inquire the reason for "that", or you question why it it "that" and not "something else". To me that sounds differently.

Comment: @ernstkl: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but -- I don't think that "Why's that?" can ever mean "Why is it that?"

Comment: @ruakh you got me right, and probably you are right as well. Therefore I tend to remove my comments, they are slightly off topic anyway

Answer (score 6):

The quoted question should fit the flow of the one the speaker is actually asking, and thus have a rising intonation.

This is generally true for very short quotations, but longer ones, especially multiple sentences, may go either way. A comma before the quote usually suggests that the quotation retains its own inflection, though this isn't a hard rule.

Comment: It depends on context - but in this context the emphasis being on the impoliteness of the question, one could raise the "weight" extremely, because this is the implied offending part of the question. In this case the cited question is intonated completely different compared to the original asker. Like 'Did he really say "Whats your !!WEIGHT!!???" - what an impolite question!'

Comment: @Falco Well put.